# How do I copy new binaries to C:\Program Files?

Tags: .net, uac, code-access-security

I'm creating a Windows app that automatically updates itself. I'm not using ClickOnce for a variety of reasons. When I try to File.Move() my updated files to C:\Program Files on Windows 7, I get the following error:

Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\<company>\<app>\<app.exe>' is denied.

I am not given a UAC prompt. The exe that I am trying to update is not currently running.

Comment: How was the application initially installed?  What account is running the program when the update is attempted (an admin or non-admin account)?

Comment: The app was initially installed using an MSI, which gives the correct UAC prompt. I tried running the app with the admin account (though not "Run As Admin"), and it throws without raising a UAC prompt. "Run As Admin" makes it work, but I don't want my users to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is UAC, even though you aren't getting a UAC prompt.

You need to change your program's manifest to automatically elevate.  (This will give you a UAC prompt)

Comment: You should only run as admin if there actually is an update to apply.

Comment: I created another exe with the proper manifest. When I have a new update to install, I call the other exe to copy the files. So the UAC prompt only appears when it needs to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make changes in the program's install folder, you don't have the required admin privileges.  Adding a manifest to your updater isn't practical, the user is quickly going to tire seeing the elevation prompt.

The only practical way is to run your updater as a scheduled task.  Those tasks are permitted to run with admin privileges because it requires admin privileges to schedule one.  Which you'll need to do with your installer.